# Unable to connectto https://www.anaconda.com to install a package

Tags: python, conda

C:\Anaconda\Scripts>conda install matplotlib
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))

C:\Anaconda\Scripts>

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In this case, the "SSL module is not available" error is the place to start. Where did your Python install come from? Who compiled it? Because the obvious interpretation is that it was compiled without OpenSSL support.

Comment: i have the same problem. i installed the latest anaconda package and cannot update it.